# How do I get the MudBlazor `context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync` event to fire on the button `OnClick` event to enable editing on the `MudDataGrid`?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, mudblazor

#### MudBlazor `context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync` not firing `StartedEditingItem` event: MudDataGrid row not editable.

I am using MudBlazor `context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync` on a MudDataGrid to enable inline editing of each meeting in a list. When I click the button, the expected event is not firing. Here is my code:

```
@page "/eventseditor"
@inject PartyTimeDbContext DbContext
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
@using PartyTime;
@using PartyTime.Shared;
@using PartyTime.Data.Models;

<MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Color="Color.Primary" Class="mb-5">Events Editor</MudText>

<MudDataGrid 
    T="Meeting" 
    Items="@Meetings" 
    EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Cell"
    StartedEditingItem="@StartedEditingItem" 
    CanceledEditingItem="@CanceledEditingItem" 
    CommittedItemChanges="@CommittedItemChanges"
    Bordered="true" 
    Dense="true"
    EditTrigger="DataGridEditTrigger.Manual"
    FixedHeader="true">

    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.Name" Title="Title" IsEditable="false" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.Description"  />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.StartTime" Title="Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.EndTime" Title="End" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.PublishTime" Title="Publish" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.UnpublishTime" Title="Unpublish" />
        <TemplateColumn Title="Edit">
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit" OnClick="@(()=>context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync())" />
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>

</MudDataGrid>

@code 
{
    private List<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Meetings = DbContext.Meetings
            .Include(m => m.Location)
            .Include(m => m.Category)
            .ToList();
    }

    void StartedEditingItem(Meeting meeting)
    {
        // code needed for editing
    }

    void CanceledEditingItem(Meeting meeting)
    {
        // code needed for canceling changes
    }

    void CommittedItemChanges(Meeting meeting)
    {
        // code needed for committing/saving changes
    }
}
```

I am following the example provided at [MudBlazor MudDataGrid Editing](https://mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#editing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data grid defaults to `ReadOnly="true"`, so once I added the attribute `ReadOnly="false"` to the `<MudDataGrid>` component, the rows became editable.

```
@page "/eventseditor"
@inject PartyTimeDbContext DbContext
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
@using PartyTime;
@using PartyTime.Shared;
@using PartyTime.Data.Models;

<MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Color="Color.Primary" Class="mb-5">Events Editor</MudText>

<MudDataGrid 
    T="Meeting" 
    Items="@Meetings" 
    ReadOnly="false"
    EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Cell"
    StartedEditingItem="@StartedEditingItem" 
    CanceledEditingItem="@CanceledEditingItem" 
    CommittedItemChanges="@CommittedItemChanges"
    Bordered="true" 
    Dense="true"
    EditTrigger="DataGridEditTrigger.Manual"
    FixedHeader="true">

    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.Name" Title="Title" IsEditable="false" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.Description"  />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.StartTime" Title="Start" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.EndTime" Title="End" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.PublishTime" Title="Publish" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="m => m.UnpublishTime" Title="Unpublish" />
        <TemplateColumn Title="Edit">
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit" OnClick="@(()=>context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync())" />
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>

</MudDataGrid>

@code 
{
    private List<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Meetings = DbContext.Meetings
            .Include(m => m.Location)
            .Include(m => m.Category)
            .ToList();
    }

    void StartedEditingItem(Meeting meeting)
    {
        // code needed for editing
    }

    void CanceledEditingItem(Meeting meeting)
    {
        // code needed for canceling changes
    }

    void CommittedItemChanges(Meeting meeting)
    {
        // code needed for committing/saving changes
    }
}
```